# How to use online API in java web Application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am working on  my college final year project and ive been developing a project in which ive to use any text to speech online api. My project is servlet and jsp based web application but i dont know how to use the API in my code. Can any one help me.

I have seen a free TTS Api such as http://www.voicerss.org/api/documentation.aspx.

Comment: Use e.g. [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/) library to call the API from your code.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Can you please give some implementations details? cause it is very new thing to me and tutorials on there website are of very high level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Fluent HC](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/fluent-hc/dependency-info.html):

```
String key = "..."; // your API key
byte[] mp3speech = Request.Get("http://api.voicerss.org/?key=" + key + "&hl=en-us&src=I+am+very+lazy+student.").execute().returnContent().asBytes();
// do anything you need with the result
```